# Is this an iterator over an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Today I wanted to propose to students a very short and stupid code as follows

```
# include <iostream>

int main()
  {
   int a[] {10, 20, 30, 40};

   for(int k=0; k != 4; ++k) std::cout << ++a[k] << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;

   }
```

in order to show how the `++` prefix operator acts in an expression.

I inadvertently mistyped the code, ending up with the following line,
in place of the one shown above:

```
for(int k=0; k != 4; ++k) std::cout << ++k[a] << ' ';
```

shortly: swapping `k` and `a` in the operand of `++`.

Well... not only this is compiled, but it gives also the correct results.
How this could be understood? Is the index of the loop interpreted as an iterator over the array `a`? Or what else?

Comment: Yeah it's a funny quirk of the language that there's no difference if you switch the array name and the index.

Comment: Enforce good coding standards, always use `{` and `}` after `for` loops.  This will help reduce injected defects that are hard to trace.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how would braces help here?

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's not a matter of helping or not.  Since the OP is teaching students, its a good idea to start good habits early.  See the MISRA coding guidelines and other guidelines.  Braces help issues where the author wants a second or third line but forgets about the `;`.  Search StackOverflow for examples.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. Meanwhile I have found the answer in the clause 8.3.4.6 of the C++ standard.